# WPF binding does not work with a UserControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

In my `MainViewModel` I have a property, which is set by the user. When a new value is received, I would like to update information at my `UserControl`. The problem is the binding does not work. The way I would like it to work is the following. After `SelectedDay` is changed, `Day` property in the user control code behind also changes, thus invoking `CalculateDay` method. However, this method is never called!

I guess, the reason is very simple and I just do not completely understand the binding mechanism, but I cannot figure out what is wrong and now I really need some help. I have already checked a number of similar questions, but never found an appropriate answer.

The code I have:

**MainViewModel**

```
private Day _selectedDay;
public Day SelectedDay
{
    get { return _selectedDay; }
    set
    {
        _selectedDay = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDay");
    }
}
```

**MainWindow XAML**

```
<controls:DayControl Day="{Binding SelectedDay, Mode=TwoWay}"></controls:DayControl>
```

**UserCotrol code behind**

```
public Day Day
{
    get { return (Day)GetValue(DayProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(DayProperty, value);
        CalculateDay();
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty DayProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Day", typeof(Day), typeof(DayControl), new PropertyMetadata(new Day()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx)

> In all but exceptional circumstances, your wrapper implementations
>   should perform only the GetValue and SetValue actions, respectively.
>   The reason for this is discussed in the topic XAML Loading and
>   Dependency Properties.

You should use the PropertyChangedCallBack in the definition for the Dependency Property instead. Following is the Code directly taken from msdn.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AquariumGraphicProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "AquariumGraphic",
  typeof(Uri),
  typeof(AquariumObject),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, 
      new PropertyChangedCallback(OnUriChanged)
  )
);
```

Define your **CalculateDay** in place of **OnUriChanged** above.

Comment: Thanks for a tip, it's a really good one. However, it does not solve my problem. `SetValue()` is not called as well and `Day` property is not updated.

Comment: Since WPF bypasses the wrappers entirely, you should not put any additional logic into the set definitions of the wrapper for your custom dependency property. If you put such logic in the set definition, then the logic will not be executed when the property is set in XAML rather than in code. You can't gurantee the invocation of Wrappers Get/Set. So drop all the logic from your Wrappers and put in in PropertyChangedCallback. The Day property wrapper is part of Dependency property definition and not your ViewModel. Get may not be called when you read Day property in your code. Same for Set

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why you use `DependencyProperty` in code behind. You have all what you need in `MainViewModel`.

In code behind just add to constructor:

```
this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

Next, move `CalculateDay` method to `MainViewModel` and invoke it in set method of `SelectedDay`